# DivideByZero Exception in NUnit TestFixture on WP7.1

Tags: .net, exception, windows-phone-7, nunit, linq-to-xml

I am implementing a data store access classes for my WP7.1 application.

The general structure of inheritance of classes is the following:

`IDataStore` - interface that declears logical operations that the application doaim classes use.

`abstract class XmlDataStore` implements the requesired by the interface functionality via XElement routines, but leaves the base data store configuration to the successor classes.

The abstract methods in `XmlDataStore` are:

```
public abstract void CreateDataStore();

public abstract void OpenDataStore();

public abstract void SaveChanges();
```

Also, an abstract class contains the const strings definitions thare used by successors:

```
protected const string xmlRoot = "Data";
protected const string booksRoot = "Records";
protected const string settingsRoot = "Settings";
```

There are two successors to `XmlDataStore`: `IsolatedStorageDataStore` and `InMemoryDataStore`.

The later was created for test purposes, so I can test the correcness of the xml-manipulation routines implemented in  `abstract XmlDataStore`.

I have added a Windows Phone Class Library to my solution. References NUnit via NuGet and have implemented one [TestFixture]:

```
[TestFixture]
public class XmlDataStoreTest
{
        private IDataStore _store;

        public XmlBookProgressStoreTest()
        {
            _store = new InMemoryXmlDataStore();
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestRegisterBookView()
        {
            _store.RegisterBookView(BookId, "TestBook");
        }
}
```

An `InMemoryDataStore` currently is the following class:

```
public class InMemoryDataStore : XmlDataStore
    {
        private XDocument _inMemDoc;

        public InMemoryDataStore()
        {
            CreateDataStore();
            OpenDataStore();
        }

        public override void CreateDataStore()
        {
            try
            {
                var root = new XElement(xmlRoot);
                root.Add(new XElement(booksRoot));
                root.Add(new XElement(settingsRoot));

                _inMemDoc = new XDocument(root);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

        }

        public override void OpenDataStore()
        {
            _deusBookDataFile = _inMemDoc;
        }

        public override void SaveChanges()
        {}
    }
}
```

Now, when I debug this class in a simple application debug, the `InMemoryDataStore` instanciates fine, but when I debug my unit test, I get a `DivideByZeroException`in this line of code: `var root = new XElement(xmlRoot);`

Clearly the problem only happens in unit test execution so it must be somehow connected to it. Why is the exception there and how can I fix it?

Comment: can you please check if the problem exists on a different testing framework ?

Comment: Will try Visual Studio unit tests and get back to you.

Comment: Tried VS Unit Testing Framework. Actually tried to try with no luck. The VS generates a test class lib project that is targeting .Net Framework 4.0, and in it, System.Xml.Linq is of a different version, rather then in the project targeting WP7.1. Maybe I should try to create a class lib project manually, without using a create test menu item from Test menu in VS2010. Will do and let you know.

Comment: xUnti won't work on WP7 project. I either have to use NUnit, or Silverlight Test Framework, which I just don't know how to use yet. I wish NUnit would just work as expected =)

Comment: Googling around revealed that: 1. This is a wide-spread problem with WP7 + NUnit. NUnit doesn't have unit testing support for Silverlight just yet. NUnit 3 should solve the problem. Thus far - a developers should use Silverlight Testing Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, this is a common problem. For Unit Testing Silverlight apps one should currently use Silverlight Testing Framework and see the results of the tests on the device's screen.

Things should change with the release of NUnit 3 which is to feature a Silverlight support.